"Leave thee alone! Look back! Ah, Goddess, see" in John Keats's "Lamia"
I am trying to understand the meaning to the following excerpt from John Keats's Lamia (full poem here):

"Leave thee alone! Look back! Ah, Goddess, see
Whether my eyes can ever turn from thee!
For pity do not this sad heart belie—


What is meant by "Leave thee alone" here?
Does the last verse mean: do not deceive my sad heart?


Are you asking from an English grammar perspective or are you looking for how the lines are to be interpreted in context of the poem?

Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is the interpretation and meaning that I am interested in.

This is Lycius’s reply to Lamia, who said, some dozen lines previously:

                                “Ah, Lycius bright,
And will you leave me on the hills alone?
Lycius, look back! and be some pity shown.”

His “Leave thee alone!” thus echoes her question “will you leave me on the hills alone?” and his  “Look back!” echoes her “Lycius, look back!”. These are exclamations of protest or incredulity—there is an implied, “How can you imagine it were possible for me to do the first, or not to do the second?”
The third line quoted in the question is an anastrophe, an inversion of the usual word order for poetic reasons. The usual order would be, “do not belie this sad heart.” “Belie” here means “contradict, misrepresent”, not “deceive”, and “this heart” means Lycius, by synecdoche.
Keats uses anastrophe a lot, but so do many poets when under the constraints of rhythm and rhyme. The table below includes a few of those we’ve seen so far in Lamia:



Anastrophe
Usual order




empty left his golden throne
left his golden throne empty


to bathe was wont
was wont to bathe


with all its pearls complete
complete with all its pearls


on his pinions lay
lay on his pinions


by my power is her beauty veil’d
her beauty is veil’d by my power


pale grew her immortality
her immortality grew pale


a dream it was
it was a dream


his eyes he bent
he bent his eyes


towards her stept
stept towards her




Thanks a lot Gareth for your answer. I did not know of the anastrophe. Only of the hyperbaton. I assume they are very similar figures of speech.
